# undefined function when using bootstrap wysiwyg meteor package

Tags: meteor, wysiwyg

i'm using this Package [enter link description here](https://github.com/mcrider/meteor-bootstrap-wysiwyg)

when i try in the console to `('#editor').wysiwyg();`
i get `undefined is not a function`

Comment: https://atmospherejs.com/?q=wysiwyg Try something newer, package you are trying to add is 2 years old, therefore probably deprecated

Comment: thanks is there a way to use this package the jquery way https://atmospherejs.com/babrahams/editable-text-wysiwyg-bootstrap-3.
cuz i have pre generated html field i need to turn into editor on templated rendered

Comment: I don't use wysiwyg, neither do I use editable, so sorry, but I can't help you further